# How to efficiently convert a set of geohashes into a polygon?

Tags: python-3.x, polygons, geohashing

I have been looking for a efficient way to convert a set of geohashes into polygons in Python, besides sometimes I obtain multipolygons instead of polygons, probably because some inner geohashes are missing. I am currently using [python-geohash](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-geohash) and [shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) and my approach consists in the following steps:

1. I convert each geohash into a polygon by extracting its corner coordinates.

   ```
   def to_polygon(geohash):
       box = Geohash.bbox(geohash)
       return Polygon([(box['e'], box['n']), (box['w'], box['n']), (box['w'], box['s']), (box['e'], box['s'])])
   ```
2. Then I `map` over the `iterable` of geohashes performing previous explained transformation.

   ```
   polygons = [to_polygon(geohash) for geohash in geohashes]
   ```
3. Finally, I combine all those polygons into a single one, by using polygon's method [union](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=polygon#object.union).

   ```
   polygon = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), polygons)
   ```

If the set of geohashes is around some thousands it may take few minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a library ([polygon-geohasher](https://github.com/Bonsanto/polygon-geohasher)) to achieve this:

```
from polygon_geohasher.polygon_geohasher import geohashes_to_polygon

geohashes = ['9bc1db2',
             '9bc1db6', 
             '9bc1db1', 
             '9bc1db0',
             '9bc1db4',
             '9bc1db9', 
             '9bc1db8',
             '9bc1dbd', 
             '9bc1db3']
polygon = geohashes_to_polygon(geohashes)
print(polygon) 
# POLYGON ((-99.71878051757812 4.483795166015625, -99.71878051757812 4.482421875, -99.72015380859375 4.482421875, -99.72152709960938 4.482421875, -99.722900390625 4.482421875, -99.722900390625 4.483795166015625, -99.722900390625 4.48516845703125, -99.722900390625 4.486541748046875, -99.72152709960938 4.486541748046875, -99.72015380859375 4.486541748046875, -99.71878051757812 4.486541748046875, -99.71878051757812 4.48516845703125, -99.71878051757812 4.483795166015625))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, your `geohashes_to_polygon` function helped me clarify how to compute the bounding box from `decode_exactly`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [geohashlite](https://github.com/qxzzxq/python-geohash)

```
# GeoHash to GeoJSON
converter_1 = geohashlite.GeoJsonHasher()
x = ['u09k', 'u095', 'u08g', 'u09h', 'u09e', 'u097']
converter_1.geohash_codes = x
converter_1.decode_geohash(multipolygon=True)
print(converter_1.geojson)
```